# Trouble with binary SMS sending and receiving on Android

Tags: android, binary, sms, telephony, telephonymanager

I'm having a problem with sending and receiving binary sms on android. I'm working on this project with a group, and other people on my team are not having this issue, but I am. We're not sure why, but if it matters, we are on different cell phone carriers. Anyways, what I am trying to do is at least be able to send a binary sms to my own phone and then receive it in order to test that both sending and receiving functionality are working.

Here's the code for my main activity where the message is sent on a button click event:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void sendBinarySMS(View view) {
    // Get the default instance of SmsManager
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

    String phoneNumber = "5558675309";
    byte[] smsBody = "Testing testing 123".getBytes();
    short port = 1234;

    // Send a text based SMS
    smsManager.sendDataMessage(phoneNumber, null, port, smsBody, null, null);
}
```

}

Here's the code where I have my receiver registered:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <receiver
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        >
        <intent-filter android:priority="10" >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.DATA_SMS_RECEIVED" />
            <data
                android:scheme="sms"
                android:host="*"
                android:port="1234" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

and here is my receiver:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] messages = null;
    String message = "";
    String sender = "";
    if (bundle == null) {
        return;
    }
    Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
    messages = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

    for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
        byte[] data = null;
        messages[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
        sender = messages[i].getOriginatingAddress();
        data = messages[i].getUserData();
        for (int index = 0; index < data.length; index++) {
            message += Character.toString((char) data[index]);
        }
    }
    processSMS(sender, message);
}

private void processSMS(String sender, String message) {
    System.out.println("Sender: " + sender + ", message = " + message);
}
```

}

Also, if this helps, I have noticed one behavioral difference that my handset has from my teammates. When I hit the button the first time (only the first time), I get a large, strange blob of text in the logs which involve telephony configuration. I suspect these may relate to the problem, but I'm not sure what to do with them. Here's a sample:

> V/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [loadFeatureFromXml] *** start feature loading from xml
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [parse] Load xml
>   V/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [getMatchedProfile] selected file : /etc/featureset.xml
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : cdma_urgent_vmwi, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : legacy_vvm_not_save, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : vzw_network_name, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : cdma_sms_nbpcd, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : copy_submit_to_uicc, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : vzw_sms_pctest, value : false
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : ecc_number_in_hidden_menu, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : cdma_cause_code_display, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : MAUNAL_TIMEZONE_SETTING_POPUP, value : false
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : support_send_burst_dtmf, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : KREncodingScheme, value : false
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : cdma_priority_indicator, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : MANAGED_TIME_LOCAL_AREAS, value : 450
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : vzw_gfit, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : MANAGED_TIME_SETTING, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : network_duplicate_message, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : sms_signature, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : handle8bit, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : cdma_sms_cdg2, value : false
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : CHANGE_CDMA_SUBSCRIPTION_TO_RUIM, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : vzw_eri, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : gsm_dcs_over_cdma_for_kddi, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : SUPPORT_E911_FOR_VOLTE, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : support_network_change_auto_retry, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : set_sms_character_encoding, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : support_vzw_Los_upgrade, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : cdma_privacy_indicator, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : do_not_save_sms_to_isis_short_code, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : sms_dan_send, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : support_emoji_in_concat_message, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : email_over_sms, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : vvm3_wap_push, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : SUPPORT_ENHANCED_VOICECALL, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : support_svlte, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : cdma_kr_testbed_mms_receive, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : should_write_messages_for_vzw, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : NITZ_WAITING_TIMEOUT, value : 10000
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : vzw_snc_email_sms, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : app_directed_sms, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : MANUAL_SELECTION_WITH_RAT, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : vzw_sms_fromvtext, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : not_support_sms_nbpcd, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : uicc_csim, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : cmas, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : revise_invalid_cdma_wappush_pdu, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : ota_for_vzw, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : store_on_usim_storage, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : SUPPORT_INFO_FOR_IMS, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : support_emergency_callback_mode_for_gsm, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : vzw_modem_data_logging, value : false
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : sms_tracker_multipart_check, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : SUPPORT_UPDATE_DEVICE_INFO, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : control_uicc_storage, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : increase_mo_msg_queue_limit_vzw, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : vzw_sms_retry_scheme, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : vzw_set_nitz, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : voicemail_urgent, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : seperate_processing_sms_uicc, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : sms_gcf_config, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : cdma_sms_display_mode, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : cdma_sms_callback, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : use_update_for_copy2sim, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : insert_boottime_for_sim_mosms, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : KSC5601Decoding, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : sms_over_lgims, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : ems_segment_timer, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : parse_email_on_uicc, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : increase_user_permit_sent_sms_max_count, value : true
>   D/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [profileToMap] add - key : support_assisted_dialing, value : true
>   V/TelephonyAutoProfiling: [loadFeatureFromXml] load feature from xml complete : {cdma_urgent_vmwi=true, vzw_network_name=true, legacy_vvm_not_save=true, cdma_sms_nbpcd=true, vzw_sms_pctest=false, copy_submit_to_uicc=true, ecc_number_in_hidden_menu=true, cdma_cause_code_display=true, support_send_burst_dtmf=true, MAUNAL_TIMEZONE_SETTING_POPUP=false, KREncodingScheme=false, vzw_gfit=true, MANAGED_TIME_LOCAL_AREAS=450, cdma_priority_indicator=true, MANAGED_TIME_SETTING=true, network_duplicate_message=true, sms_signature=true, cdma_sms_cdg2=false, handle8bit=true, vzw_eri=true, CHANGE_CDMA_SUBSCRIPTION_TO_RUIM=true, gsm_dcs_over_cdma_for_kddi=true, support_network_change_auto_retry=true, SUPPORT_E911_FOR_VOLTE=true, set_sms_character_encoding=true, support_vzw_Los_upgrade=true, cdma_privacy_indicator=true, support_emoji_in_concat_message=true, sms_dan_send=true, do_not_save_sms_to_isis_short_code=true, email_over_sms=true, SUPPORT_ENHANCED_VOICECALL=true, vvm3_wap_push=true, support_svlte=true, cdma_kr_testbed_mms_receive=true, should_write_messages_for_vzw=true, NITZ_WAITING_TIMEOUT=10000, vzw_snc_email_sms=true, app_directed_sms=true, MANUAL_SELECTION_WITH_RAT=true, vzw_sms_fromvtext=true, not_support_sms_nbpcd=true, uicc_csim=true, cmas=true, ota_for_vzw=true, revise_invalid_cdma_wappush_pdu=true, store_on_usim_storage=true, SUPPORT_INFO_FOR_IMS=true, support_emergency_callback_mode_for_gsm=true, vzw_modem_data_logging=false, sms_tracker_multipart_check=true, SUPPORT_UPDATE_DEVICE_INFO=true, control_uicc_storage=true, increase_mo_msg_queue_limit_vzw=true, vzw_sms_retry_scheme=true, vzw_set_nitz=true, voicemail_urgent=true, seperate_processing_sms_uicc=true, sms_gcf_config=true, cdma_sms_display_mode=true, cdma_sms_callback=true, use_update_for_copy2sim=true, sms_over_lgims=true, KSC5601Decoding=true, insert_boottime_for_sim_mosms=true, ems_segment_timer=true, parse_email_on_uicc=true, support_assisted_dialing=true, increase_user_permit_sent_sms_max_count=true}

Comment: If your phone is running Marshmallow or above, and your `targetSdkVersion` is >=23, have you requested the `RECEIVE_SMS` permission at runtime?

Comment: My phone is running lollipop, so I don't think I have to do that

Comment: Nope, ya don't. Remove the `host` attribute from the `<data>` element in your manifest.

Comment: Ok, removed that. Doesn't seem like anything has changed

Comment: Hmm, well, it might just be your device/carrier. Everything else looks good. Is your `SmsReceiver` in the same folder as `MainActivity`? You sure you got your number right? (I know the one in the post is Jenny's.) Have you tried putting some log prints at the top of `onReceive()` to be sure that it's not somehow failing before the `processSMS()` call?

Comment: Haha, just double checked my number, it's right. I did put some log calls at the top of onReceive(), not getting anything so far. That would suck if it was just my phone. For reference, it is an LG-G2 on Verizon

Comment: Well, Verizon really shouldn't be choking on a simple data SMS. I just put your posted code in a test project to make sure I'm not missing anything, and it's good. Do you have the correct SMS-related classes imported? E.g., it should be `android.telephony.SmsManager`, not `android.telephony.gsm.SmsManager`. Also, you might try passing a `PendingIntent` as the fifth argument in the `sendDataMessage()` call, and check the results to see if it's sending OK. Can you send to one of your friends' phones?

Comment: So, it looks like it's not sending. PendingIntents aren't giving error or success messages. The plot thickens...

Comment: That's a bummer. You mean the `PendingIntent` isn't firing at all, or you're getting an undefined result code? Can you send a regular text message with `SmsManager`?

Comment: Yeah, the only way I got it to fire was by removing my SIM card. Only then would it even give any kind of response (service not available). Oddly enough, sending regular text messages works for me